# Does this usage of array_filter() result in undefined behavior?

Tags: php, recursion, undefined-behavior

So the manual for [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) says;

> If the array is changed from the callback function (e.g. element added, deleted or unset) the behavior of this function is undefined.

and I stumbled upon the following code snippet in my codebase (example variable definitions added for reproducibility):

```
$enabledGroups = array(1, 3, 5);

$subgroups = array(
    array('nid' => 1),
    array('nid' => 2),
    array(
        'nid' => 3,
        'children' => array(
            array ('nid' => 4),
            array ('nid' => 5)
        )
    )
);

$filterFunc = function (&$v) use ($enabledGroups, &$filterFunc) {
    if($v['children']) {
        $v['children'] = array_filter($v['children'], $filterFunc);
    }

    return in_array($v['nid'], $enabledGroups);
};

$subgroups = array_filter($subgroups, $filterFunc);
```

From the wording of the warning in the manual, I'm not totally sure, if this usage constitutes undefined behavior.

So my question is: **Does a recursive usage of array_filter() like shown above, result in undefined behavior, or does it not?**